# How to Align Text Consistently in Editable and Non-Editable Modes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app where I need to switch between an editable and non-editable mode for displaying text. The text should be 100% aligned in both modes. However, I'm encountering an issue where the TextEditor aligns its content to the top, while the Text view content gets centered, despite using the same frame size for both.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
//
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Tap to edit"
    @State private var isEditable: Bool = false
    @State private var textStyle = NSFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body) // Example styling
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) { // Leading alignment; top alignment is implicit by frame size
                if isEditable {
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 200) // Same frame size for both views
                        .font(.custom(textStyle.fontName, size: textStyle.pointSize)) // Ensure font consistency
                        .border(.orange)
                    
                } else {
                    Text(text)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 200) // Same frame size for both views
                        .font(.custom(textStyle.fontName, size: textStyle.pointSize)) // Ensure font consistency
                        .border(.blue)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.isEditable = true
                        }
                }
            }
            
            Button("Done") {
                self.isEditable = false
                // Add logic to hide keyboard if necessary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
Question:
How can I ensure that the text in both the TextEditor and Text views is aligned consistently at the top when switching between editable and non-editable modes?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.topLeading` alignment to the frame modifier on the `Text`. Also:

- if you want both versions to be exactly aligned, you might want to tweak the padding and line spacing of the `Text`
- to be able to tap anywhere, add `.contentShape` too:

```swift
Text(text)
    .padding(.leading, 5)
    .padding(.trailing, 20)
    .lineSpacing(0.6)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 200, alignment: .topLeading) // Same frame size for both views
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    // other modifiers as before
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thanks a lot! but I need a solution that I can modify everything (line spacing, padding, etc,) and it will keep consistent across both views.